# Pixel Shader performance in Directx9 not equivalent to Opengl ES2.0

Tags: opengl-es-2.0, slimdx, hlsl2glsl

I am using a drop effect by the help of pixel shader in directx-9 to be specific SlimDX.Direct3D9 written in hlsl used for transition between two images. I have written the same pixel shader in glsl language to be used in an android project using java 6.0.

The issue here is with the performance difference in both the machines. Android machines is showing smooth transition but there is a visible pixelation in Windows machines during transition. Pixel shader 2.0 version is being used in directx project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a couple of pictures would help immensely.

It could be a difference in sampling coordinates. Make sure you are getting 1:1 texture/pixel mapping.

Another possibility could be that the filtering is set to point instead of linear.

Comment: TextureFilter did the job. Thanks.